# Modify batch script to also get Hours and Minutes from %currentdate%

Tags: datetime, batch-file

I need to modify a Windows batch file that was written by a developer who has since quit.  Here's part of what's already there:

```
set date/t=%currentdate%
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date/t') do (
set fmonth=%%a) & (set fdate=%%b) & (set fyear=%%c)
```

I kinda, barely understand how/why this works, and it does work as designed.  If run this today, fmonth is 08, fdate is 17, and fyear if 2012.  But what I also need out of this is hours and seconds. I have been guessing and googling now for way too long, and I need professional help.

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The rene answer will not work in all locales. Some use comma, some use period as the decimal point. Plus the solution can be condensed to a single FOR statement. The following should work in all locales. The fractional seconds are actually centiseconds (1/100), not milliseconds (1/1000).

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%A in ("%time%") do (
  set fhour=%%A
  set fmin=%%B
  set fsec=%%C
  set fcsec=%%D
)
```

If you want to do mathematical computations with the values then you have additional work to do. Values less than 10 will by zero prefixed, which might not seem like a problem. But SET treats any number that is zero prefixed as octal notation, and 08 and 09 are not valid octal digits.

There are a few ways to strip off the leading zero, but the most convenient is to use a bit of math. Simply prefix the value with 100 and then take the modulous 100 (remainder after dividing by 100). All the assignments can be done with a single SET /A statement.

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%A in ("%time%") do set /a "fhour=100%%A%%100, fmin=100%%B%%100, fsec=100%%C%%100, fcsec=100%%D%%100"
```

Comment: The prefix could be just `1`, unless I'm missing something. Other than that, agree entirely.

Comment: @AndriyM - I thought about that, and I believe it is true for the minutes and seconds. But I'm not sure if the hours are always 0 prefixed. It could be prefixed with 10 instead of 100 either way. I believe the 100 comes from a generic solution I had seen where there may be 0, 1, or 2 digits, possibly 0 prefixed, possibly not.

Comment: I see now, thanks for your explanation, it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

split based on %time%

```
set time=%time%:
for /f "tokens=1-3,* delims=:" %%k in ("%time%") do (set fhour=%%k) & (set fminute=%%l) & (set fsecfrac=%%m)
for /f "tokens=1-3,* delims=," %%k in ("%fsecfrac%") do (set fsecond=%%k) & (set fmsec=%%l)
```